# Empty grid using Troy Goode's PagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Just started using the PagedList and cannot get any data to appear in the grid.

The View is as follows:

```
@model StJudes_Donor.Web.ViewModels.Donor.DonorIndexViewModel

@using PagedList.Mvc; 
@using PagedList; 

<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h2>List</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var donor in Model.OnePageOfDonors) {
        <li>@donor.Fullname</li>
    }
</ul>

<div>
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.OnePageOfDonors, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</div>
```

Model.OnePageOfDonors is defined in DonorIndexViewModel as

```
    public IPagedList<DonorSummaryDTO> OnePageOfDonors { get; set; }
```

There is (correct) data appearing in Model.OnePageOfDonors, but nothing appears in the actual grid, see below.

[image: Result]

The paging buttons themselves do work, i.e. the data pages as expected.

CSS file is present, and can click-navigate to it in Visual Studio. No errors showing in the browser developer window.

So, everything appears fine except for the actual rendering of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the [Getting Started with EF 6 and MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) I found I had to put a table in front of the @Html.PagedListPager part.